# Remove query strings from static resources - not wordpress

Tags: string, static, resources

When using GTMETRIX.com to evaluate my site it returns:

**Remove query strings from static resources**

The offender is:

http://www.xxxxxx.com/img/slide1.jpg?1371550256182

I know this occurs because of somthing in my .htaccess file:

```
# CACHE SYSTEM
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch     "\.(js|css|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4|html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|fav|woff|eot|svg|ttf)    $">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2014 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```

what i note is that the slide1.jpg?**1371550256182** , numbers change evrytime.

is there a way to solve this issue, it only happens with with these banner slides that are approx 200kb in size.

I have read this link [HERE](http://www.clarkeology.com/m/14148/Remove+query+strings+from+static+resources).

but am not sure if it is the way to go. Have been pulling my hair out trying to solve this so any help or guide would be amazing!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess file looks like you have set a fixed date and time `Thu, 15 Apr 2014 20:00:00 GMT` which will mean that you don't actually have any caching enabled for those file types. Have a look at this [htaccess boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache) for examples on how to properly set your [expires](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/web_performance/expires_headers.conf) headers.

Next, that querystring `?1371550256182` is added most likely by your CMS platform (what are you using?) so you would need to identify where that is added, and either remove it directly, or use some sort of hook / plugin / module to strip off the querystring for these images.

Without a bit more detail on your setup, people won't be able to help you further.